# Custom JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Based on the user session I have to display different stuff on JSP.

Something is wrong, please advice

```
  <c:if test="${session.getAttribute("userEmail")}">

        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="Ansari@precise-one.com"> //here if test is not null
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" width="40%" nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align: left;">
            <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/icons/chevron_double.gif"/>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" class="underlinedLinksLic">Google</a>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/icons/chevron_double.gif"/>
            <a href="http://www.gmail.com" class="underlinedLinksLic">Gmail</a></td>  

        </tr>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="test@liferay.com">   //here if session is null
        <tr>Hello</tr>  
        </c:when>

        <tr height="3px;">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

    </c:choose>
```

Comment: "Something is wrong" What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<c:if test="${session.getAttribute("userEmail")}">
```

This ain't going to work. This should have been

```
<c:if test="${not empty userEmail}">
```

The `<c:if>` block will then be entered whenever the scoped attribute `userEmail` is not `null` or empty string. To show some stuff when the `userEmail` attribute is `null` or empty string, then do so:

```
<c:if test="${empty userEmail}">
```

Further, those String comparisons

```
<c:when test="Ansari@precise-one.com">
<c:when test="test@liferay.com">
```

should have been

```
<c:when test="${userEmail == 'Ansari@precise-one.com'}">
<c:when test="${userEmail == 'test@liferay.com'}">
```

Knowing those facts, you should be able to reconstruct your `<c:if>` and `<c:choose>` blocks more appropriately. Here's an example:

```
<c:if test="${not empty userEmail}">
    This block will be displayed when attribute `userEmail` is not empty.

    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${userEmail == 'Ansari@precise-one.com'}">
            This block will be displayed when `userEmail` matches Ansari@precise-one.com.
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${userEmail == 'test@liferay.com'}">  
            This block will be displayed when `userEmail` matches test@liferay.com.
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            There must always be a `c:otherwise` block. 
            This will be displayed when attribute `userEmail` doesn't match anything.
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${empty userEmail}">
    This block will be displayed when attribute `userEmail` is empty.
</c:if>
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 5 tutorial - JSP Standard Tag Library (JSTL)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html)
- [Java EE 5 tutorial - Examples of EL expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaim)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use session object (depends on how you mark in session that user logged in):

```
session.getAttribute("logged-in") == true
```